# Read file segment via Random Access File

Tags: java, io

I'm using `RandomAccessFile` for writing segments. And now I want to read some file segments but have problems with the end of the reading.

For example, I want to read one file page (each page contains 512 bytes).

```
var totalRead = 0;
var readingByte = 0;
val bytesToRead = 512; // Each file page - 512 bytes
var randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(dbmsFile, "rw");
randomAccessFile.seek(pageId * PAGE_SIZE); // Start reading from chosen page (by pageId)
valr stringRepresentation = new StringBuilder("");

while (totalRead < bytesToRead) {
     readingBytes = randomAccessFile.read();
     totalRead += readingBytes;
     stringRepresentation.append((char) readingBytes); 
}
```

But this approach is not right, because actually, it's reading the non-full pages, just a small part of it. Because 512 - around 41 file records. And just because I'm parsing it symbol by symbol, it cannot be correct. How can I do it better?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is adding the value of the byte to `totalRead` rather than increment by 1, so it will count to 512 much faster than expected and miss a section of data. The loop should check for and exit if `randomAccessFile.read()` returns -1 / EOF:

```
while (totalRead < bytesToRead && (readingByte = randomAccessFile.read()) != -1) {
     totalRead++;
     stringRepresentation.append((char) readingByte); 
}
```

Note that you this code may not handle all byte to char conversions correctly as it casts a byte to char.